# How to insert new array at every index of parent array

Tags: php, arrays

hello I want to get this type of functionality in custom php.

please see the picture
[image]

Comment: Your question is not much clear .What you are trying to achieve and what you have tried .

Comment: I am trying to fetch data from mysql table . and trying to represent that that in an array shown in picture

Comment: put your PHP code here

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_ functions. They were deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed in 7.0. However, the mysqli_ functions are still available.

Comment: However, it's recommended to use mysqli instead of mysql

Answer (score 0):

Change **mysql_fetch_assoc** to **mysql_fetch_array**.

However, it's recommended to use mysqli instead of mysql

Comment: @اعظممقصود, In stackoverflow, you should put your codes. not screenshots. Otherwise, you would get minus points and no answer